# AWS RDS always with 10 connections open using Spring Boot (JPA)

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I'm having a problem in my project where my database has always 10 connections open. I'm using a Spring Boot Application (REST API) which is running on Elastic Beanstalk.

The 10 connections appear right after the application starts, without any query to the database. In this moment I have 4 repositories classes that look like this:

```
    @Repository
@Transactional()
public class FieldJpaRepository {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Field> findAll(){ //JPQL
        TypedQuery<Field> namedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("find_all_fields", Field.class);
        return namedQuery.getResultList();
    }

    public Field findById(int id){
        return entityManager.find(Field.class,id);
    }

    public List<Field> findAreaFields(float minLat, float maxLat, float minLng, float maxLng){
        return entityManager.createQuery("FROM Field f WHERE f.lat BETWEEN :minLat AND :maxLat AND f.lng BETWEEN :minLng AND :maxLng ", Field.class)
                .setParameter("minLat", minLat)
                .setParameter("maxLat", maxLat)
                .setParameter("minLng", minLng)
                .setParameter("maxLng", maxLng)
                .getResultList();
    }

    public Field updateOrInsertField(Field field){
        return entityManager.merge(field);
    }

    public void deleteField(int id){
        Field findField = findById(id);
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.contains(findField) ? findField : entityManager.merge(findField));
    }


}
```

My application.properties file is the following:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=********
spring.datasource.username=******
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Could I be doing something wrong? Am I missing any configuration parameter?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize` to a value that fits.

Explanation:

- Hikari is the default JDBC Connection Pool for Spring Boot since 2.0
- It opens up the connections to the database upfront and keeps them in the idle pool
- Default is 10
- `spring.datasource.hikari.*` are specific settings for Hikari
- [Hikari Options as explained here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)

Comment: Thank you! I will explore the hikari options for a better understanding.